# Google Oauth for installed apps using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, oauth, google-oauth

I am trying to do  Google Oauth using javascript in my android or tizen device. i dont want to use phone gap or other library, i am using jquery. I am able to get sigin page in phone's browser and after accepting permissions browser is redirecting me to a web page saying copy this code and paste in your application.sucess code ex."4/wxtgskd_jsdskeehd". But i dont know what do to from here. how to copy this code or how to do full oauth from here. or how to go back to my app from browser.
Below is the full code of oauth.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="js/lib/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var OAUTHURL    =   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
        var VALIDURL    =   'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
        var SCOPE       =   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
        var CLIENTID    =   '103321196121-1adn1lgikd9sepmk6kp4lel1i72fhf96.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        var REDIRECT    =   'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
        var LOGOUT      =   'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
        var TYPE        =   'code';
        var _url        =   OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
        var acToken;
        var tokenType;
        var expiresIn;
        var user;
        var code;
        var loggedIn    =   false;

        function login() {
            var win         =   window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600'); 

            var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
                try {

                    if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {

                        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);

                        var url =   win.document.URL;
                        code= gup(url, 'code');
                        console.log(url);
                        acToken =   gup(url, 'access_token');
                        tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                        expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                        win.close();

                        validateToken(acToken);
                    }
                } catch(e) {
                }
            }, 500);
             alert(win.document.URL);
        }

        function validateToken(token) {
            $.ajax({
                url: VALIDURL + token,
                data: null,
                success: function(responseText){  
                    getUserInfo();
                    loggedIn = true;
                    $('#loginText').hide();
                    $('#logoutText').show();
                },  
                dataType: "jsonp"  
            });
        }

        function getUserInfo() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
                data: null,
                success: function(resp) {
                    user    =   resp;
                    console.log(user);
                    $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
                    $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
                },
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        }

        //credits: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
        function gup(url, name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\#&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( url );
            if( results == null )
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }

        function startLogoutPolling() {
            $('#loginText').show();
            $('#logoutText').hide();
            loggedIn = false;
            $('#uName').text('Welcome ');
            $('#imgHolder').attr('src', 'none.jpg');
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' onClick='login();' id="loginText"'> Click here to login </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none" id="logoutText" target='myIFrame' onclick="myIFrame.location='https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout'; startLogoutPolling();return false;"> Click here to logout </a>
    <iframe name='myIFrame' id="myIFrame" style='display:none'></iframe>
    <div id='uName'></div>
    <img src='' id='imgHolder'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'token' (instead of 'code') response_type.

token flow will the access token directly in the URL hash, whereas the code flow will return a grant so that you can get access token from token endpoint.